# In the sentence "Within these pages {is/are} the who's who..." should I use "is" or "are" ?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Within these pages **is/are** the who’s who in our community.

My question is which verb is correct- "is" or "are" and why.

Comment: "are" is the correct one I think, because of the word "community" which means there is more than one person. Also I think the sentence starts like this "The people within these pages are the...."

Comment: The idiomatic form **Who's Who** is effectively a (singular) "book title", similar to, for example, **The Bible**. Your sample text is thus inherently awkward because it creates an unavoidable "plurality clash" - as with *[Within/in] these pages is/are the Bible of how to learn English.* You'd do better to abandon the construction completely, and go for something like *These pages are the Who's Who of modern linguistics, This book is the Bible of learning English.*

Comment: "Community" is a group noun. "This community is poor" is correct, and "the community are poor" is incorrect.

Comment: @Jeff: That may be so in AmE, but so far as I'm concerned (as a Brit), the plurality of ***the community*** (like ***the company*** and ***the family***) is "contextually flexible". I've no problem with [*County Councillor Ros Binks said: “Nobody objected to housing on the site, but **the community were united** in their campaign to prevent a cramped and poorly designed development with little consideration for the unique setting or its residents.”*](https://theisleofthanetnews.com/reading-street-residents-celebrated-appeal-dismissal-of-plan-for-club-union-site-development/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, British English and American English differ in their usage with respect to group nouns or at least some group nouns. Thank you. I should have made that clear. I cannot say how the British treat lists. It is certainly not grammatical in American English to say "My shopping list for today contain many items." Perhaps it is grammatical in Britain; I have never been there.

Comment: @Jeff: <Sigh> I've never been to the US, but I can read and listen to AmE easily enough. The thing is, although I'm perfectly happy with usages like *Microsoft **are** planning to release Windoze 11 next year*, I'm also perfectly happy with *IBM is sticking with x86 architecture*. So if it hadn't been pointed out to me, I might not notice that most Americans avoid my first (plural) form. But surely if you're one of those "most Americans", you must have noticed that Brits don't always follow your "rule" there. By the same token, you'd notice if we said *Your list **are** incomplete* (we don't).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP is about a kind of list. A list may contain multiple items. That British speakers frequently use the plural with "government" is consistent with the British system of parliamentary democracy. That US citizens almost invariably use the singular with "government" is consistent with a different form of democracy. But I don't see that the differences between British and American usages of some group nouns is highly pertinent to the question asked unless those differences apply to a list. I doubt that they do, but I shall let you speak for British English.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't think the fact that many Brits are happy with *The government are challenging the EU directive* (or better, *The cabinet are united on this issue*) has anything to do with the fact that our system of parliamentary democracy is different to that of the US (how would any such principle translate to things like ***company, family***, where we often do the same?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You may be correct. You were asking earlier about my knowledge of British English. It is limited to what I have chosen to read. The British usage of "government" as a plural is quite familiar to me from that reading and made sense to me as reflecting a a real difference in political process. If I have read things like "The community are united," I probably read right past it though it sounds very wrong to me. Mental auto-correct or auto-corrupt if you prefer.

Comment: @Jeff: oic. I can't say exactly why it's "obvious" to me that ***list*** can only be singular, whereas ***government, company, family, couple, pair*** can vary according to context. But come to that, I'm sure if I'd ever seen/heard *The pair **is** sitting over there* from an AmE source it would sound so weird I'd be bound to remember it (which I don't). So maybe the AmE standard is a bit flexible sometimes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's interesting. American English, particularly in speech, may have a smaller set of group nouns that can take singular or plural verbs depending on context. I would probably not say "That pair of socks are already clean," and I certainly would not write it, but I suspect some other Americans might.

Answer (score 1):

"Who's who" is a description of a kind of list and sometimes the legal title of such a list. Although the list contains information about multiple people, it is a single list. The technically correct verb is "is" rather than "are."

Moreover, the sentence asked about is incorrect whatever verb is chosen.

"Within these pages is the "Who's Who" of our community" is correct if what is intended to be referenced is the trademarked publication known by that name.

"Within these pages is a "who's who" of our community" and "Within these pages is a who's who of our community" are correct (though the first is preferable) if what is intended to be described is a list performing the same function as the trademarked publication.

Answer (score -1):

“Are” is the correct one because it refers to the “who’s who” - multiple people not just one in the community

Comment: Hmm. "Who's who" seems to be a contraction of "who is who," which seems to refer to a single individual. "Family," "class" and "community" are all examples of group nouns, which are conceived as single entities although comprising multiple individuals.

Comment: FumbleFingers has pointed out correctly that British English has more complex usages with respect to group nouns than was indicated by my previous comment.